# CMD commands: Conjuction [wsgen: wsdl and inlineScemas]

Tags: cmd, wsdl, wsgen

-inlineSchemas
This option produces inline schemas in the generated wsdl. This must be used in conjunction with the -wsdl option.

Above lines are written in Oracle docs "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/wsgen.htm#JSWOR739",

My command: wsgen -verbose -keep -cp . net.example.services.Tryservice -wsdl-inlineSchemas

where "net.example.services.Tryservice" is the path to class file of my java project and wsdl along with inlineSchemas are commands to generate wsdl.

Am i doing correct conjuction of both commands wsdl and inlineSchemas??

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is

wsgen -verbose -keep -cp . net.example.services.Tryservice -inlineSchemas -wsdl